# Realm observe notifications - time sensitive

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, realm, observers

I need to observe for realm objects that fall into specific time range, and cannot figure out if it is possible to create a dynamic date as a predicate for the query.

For example, I want to observe for chnages on objects with lastModifiedDate in the past 10 minutes. So I do this:

```
items = realm.where(Item::class.java)
                    .greaterThan("lastModifiedDate", Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (1000 * 60 * 10)))
                    .sort("creationDate", Sort.DESCENDING)
                    .findAllAsync()
```

The observer notifications are running just fine, but as time passes, the value of `Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (1000 * 60 * 10))` that I passed initially is no longer relevant.

Currently I am re-allocating the query and the the change listener every 10 minutes to keep the data relevant, and i was wondering if any of you may know a dynamic solution to prevent refreshing the observer query every 10 minutes.

Comment: This is a great question! Unfortunately, it's not directly possible as the date is set when the predicate is created. Could you add an observer to all of the objects and watch for modified events, ignoring any that were not modified in the last 10 minutes?